# What informative and yet easy-to-read introductory books in English are there for Spanish Phonology?

Tags: phonology, reference-request, spanish

I had my eyes on The Phonology of Spanish by Iggy Roca but I can't find the book in any store, neither it's ISBN or even it's cover! Evidence indicates that it wasn't even published but it pertained to a series called The Phonology of The World's Languages and the phonology book I'm looking for would more or less follow the structure of those of this series.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Books:

- Hualde, José Ignacio, 2005, [*The Sounds of Spanish*](https://books.google.com/books?id=FUCRR4c-KuMC), Cambridge University Press
- Macpherson, I. R., 1975, [*Spanish Phonology: Descriptive and Historical*](https://books.google.com/books?id=9VrpAAAAIAAJ), Manchester University Press
- Harris, James, 1969, *Spanish Phonology*, MIT Press ([original thesis](https://dspace.mit.edu/handle/1721.1/12999))
- Dalbor, John B., 1997, [*Spanish Pronunciation: Theory and Practice*](https://books.google.com/books?id=qYh7QgAACAAJ), 3rd ed., Holt, Rinehart and Winston
- Cressey, William Whitney, 1978, [*Spanish Phonology and Morphology: A Generative View*](https://books.google.com/books?id=xMBCMh3GETsC), Georgetown University Press
- Canfield, D. Lincoln, 1981, [*Spanish Pronunciation in the Americas*](https://books.google.com/books?id=G8ZY3dVGF7cC), University of Chicago Press
- Penny, Ralph, 2000, [*Variation and Change in Spanish*](https://books.google.com/books?id=h7Qhxv_BZ-8C), Cambridge University Press

JIPA articles:

- Martínez-Celdrán, Eugenio, Ana Ma. Fernández-Planas & Josefina Carrera-Sabaté, 2003, ["Castilian Spanish"](https://www.cambridge.org/core/services/aop-cambridge-core/content/view/39B1C556856D62AF8FC53D3F22435750/S0025100303001373a.pdf/castilian_spanish.pdf), *Journal of the International Phonetic Association*, 33(2), pp. 255–259
- Avelino, Heriberto, 2018, ["Mexico City Spanish"](https://www.cambridge.org/core/services/aop-cambridge-core/content/view/C35C97AE9A19C9C222FD614D2D4125AA/S0025100316000232a.pdf/mexico_city_spanish.pdf), *Journal of the International Phonetic Association*, 48(2), pp. 223–230
- Coloma, Germán, 2018, ["Argentine Spanish"](https://ucema.edu.ar/u/gcoloma/ArgentineSpanish.pdf), *Journal of the International Phonetic Association*, 48(2), pp. 243–250
- Monroy, Rafael & Juan Manuel Hernández-Campoy, 2015, ["Murcian Spanish"](https://www.cambridge.org/core/services/aop-cambridge-core/content/view/75BD116FA03DFECFCF294B632467613C/S0025100314000231a.pdf/murcian_spanish.pdf), *Journal of the International Phonetic Association*, 45(2), pp. 229–240

Comment: Wow, that's an incredible list. Thanks again, Nardog.